# An employee called me "boss", but I don't like it. How can I colloquially say that?

Tags: nouns, colloquialisms

I'm a Coordinator at an English course in a small city in Brazil, and one of the teachers called me "boss" today. However, I don't appreciate being called that, therefore I'd like to tell him not to do so. I'd rather do it in a colloquial way, though. So, how can I say it?

> Hey, man. There's no need for this "boss" thing, you know.
>
> Come on, man. Don't "boss" me. There's no need for that.

Could you guys give me other examples of how you would say it with your own words?! I have no idea how to say that colloquially.

Comment: Although I understand what you meant, normally "Don't boss me" sounds like "Don't tell me what to do".

Comment: Humn, that's something I would never realize by myself. Thank you so much @NVZ. How would you say it?

Comment: I have had somewhat similar problems, cuz my name is so long and people get confused on what to call me. I say "Just call me (my preferred name here)". And my preferred name varies depending on the person calling me.

Comment: In parts of the US "boss" is a colloquial term that implies little (if anything) about the "official" relationship between the two parties.  It's almost a term of affection.  I used to work with a guy who called almost everyone "boss".

Comment: @HotLicks  Could you tell us what parts of the US?

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. In India, it's used to *flatter* a friend when they've helped you some way (financially, mostly). "Thanks for the tickets, man! You're the boss"

Comment: Is the person who said it a native speaker who would understand English idioms?  If so, you could say, "Oh no...none of that "boss" stuff here!"

Comment: He's Brazilian, too, @KristinaLopez. However, we tend to use English with ourselves all the time, since it's a learning environment over here. Your suggestion is pretty good, by the way! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Centaurus - US Midwest, though the guy I'm thinking of was from New York.

Comment: @HotLicks, we have a similar term here in Brazil, but since I'm his Coordinator, I'd rather avoid this kind of "positioning" terms, you know?!

Comment: Just tell him "Please use 'Your Majesty'."

Comment: Seriously, tell them "Don't call me 'boss'.   Either use 'Fred' or 'Your Majesty'."

Comment: He could have called you worse things! Try calling him *boss* and see how he reacts.

Comment: @HotLicks I too have known people to use *boss* as a form of address to almost anyone - in Britain. Also *squire*, or *chief* - ironically of course.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind:  Some people have a mild form of [face blindness](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/08/30/face-blind) and may not be able to recall your name immediately, even if they work with you daily.  These people will often adapt some sort of defensive mechanism, such as calling everyone "boss", to conceal their disability.  Insisting that the individual always call you by a fixed name could create significant stress for him.

Comment: You could go Randy Newman on him and say "I'm tired of being the boss. Why don't you be the boss for a while." http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/randynewman/mylifeisgood.html Or you could just call him Bruce.

Comment: Colloquially? Easy. Just make every other word a swear word and throw in some *dudes!* Did you mean, to say it in a *non-offensive* way? That is unnecessary. If you've been offended, demand your satisfaction. If this person is your subordinate, it was correctly used, but as the boss it's up to you to tell them what to call you. Used between co-workers, it *is* a term of endearment, one that often **humorously attempts to deflect responsibility**. "Hey, where's the boss?" - "You the boss today, yo." - "Aww, crap..."

Comment: Is there something wrong with just saying "don't call me boss"?

Comment: @HotLicks +1 "face blindness". Saved me a question. I call most of my friends *muthey* (pearl), not only cuz it's nice, but also cuz I forget their names too often.

Comment: @DCShannon - What you said. And maybe put a _please_ in front of it for good measure: _Please don't call me "boss" anymore; I'd rather be called by my first name._

Answer (score 11):

Language is a tool. Whether or not you have a hammer or a pillow, if you attack someone with it, the intent will do damage. In this instance, choosing the "best" words is not based on what you are trying to *communicate,* but on what you are trying to accomplish: to *commune*.

> communication (n.) late 14c., ... from
>   Latin *communicationem* ... "join, unite, participate in," literally
>   "to make common," from *communis*

Successful communication joins people together: a colloquialism is no more or less powerful than other words.

EDIT
The original poster commented that he is the boss of the employee and that he wants to keep the discussion "informal." Maybe I am viewing this entire question through the lens of *communis*, but if my perception is accurate, then the following may help.

Employee: Hey, boss!

Boss: Hey, Jason! Call me, "Lou." When you call me, "Boss," it puts an artificial divide between us. We work together, as a team, so "Lou" is perfect.

Employee: No problem. You're the boss, Lou.

Together: [laughing]

Comment: + 1 for sensible advice.

Comment: I asked for a colloquial expression not to sound formal with him. Actually, my intention is to sound as informal as our work environment allows, which is in between formal and informal. So colloquial, here, would sound good, I just don't know how to express it withouth sounding like his boss, which I am.

Comment: Sensible advice does not of itself constitute an acceptable 'answer'. This is a 'comment'.

Comment: Your edit was fantastic, @hunterhogan. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 6):

Something my dad would say when people called him boss (or sir, for that matter) was, "Don't call me boss, I work for a living. Please call me..."  I always liked it because it's a bit funny while still getting your point across.

Answer (score 3):

It would have been easier if you'd done it at the first instance; then something like "Hey, no need for that.  '_____' is fine." or "'Boss'?  Please!  Just '_____'!" would have worked.  Too late for that now, though, I guess.  Best I can come up with at this point would be along the lines of "Uh… could you call me '_____' instead of 'boss'?"

On the other hand, I have to imagine a denizen of a small city in Brazil is not going to be nearly as sensitive to this formal/informal nuance you're seeking anyway.  Just be cheerful when you say it and anything should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

> Please, call me Loureiro.  My mother worked hard to give me that name.

The first is colloquial.  The second is a little levity to take away the sting.

Say it with a gentle smile and firm eye contact and they may take your point.  They may even remember your name.

That said, best to do such things in private if you're going to make a thing about it.  Praise in public.  Correct in private.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are "the new guy"? 
Since you've let the first opportunity for correction to lapse, it may be best to respond at the next opportunity with something like, "Boss? Hmmm. Is there a more 'fun' nickname you can think of?" 
With a smile, of course. :)

Answer (score -2):

There's no need to make this complicated. You don't want to be called "boss", so say "don't call me boss". Easy.

The obvious follow-up question is "Okay, what should I call you, then?"

So preempt that and follow with what they should call you.

Assuming your actual name is Loureiro:

> Don't call me "boss", call me "Loureiro".

As far as your concerns regarding seeming "bossy", the tone with which you deliver this statement, or any of the other answers here, is going to be *much* more important the actual words you use. If you sound angry and snappy, then it won't matter how nice you put it. If you sound casual and unoffended, then a straightforward statement like this will be just fine.

Comment: "don't call me boss" is way too bossy/imperative for me to use with me team. I try to keep the environment here as casual as possible, however professional at the same time. I just didn't think of an answer right away, that's why I cam here to ask for help ^^

Comment: I have a hard time imagining anyone taking such a simple statement as being "too bossy". The tone of your statement is going to matter more than the content.